# Do async validation on form builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm usinig the flutter form builder, and I'm trying to fetch some data from the server if the name is valid/unique.

I implemented an extra FieldValidator :

```
static FormFieldValidator isUniqueHorseName({
    dynamic version,
    String errorText = "Horse already exist.",
  }) {
    return (valueCandidate) {
      print(valueCandidate);
      Future<bool> isUnique = HorseRepository().isUnique(valueCandidate);
      print(isUnique);
      return null;
    };
  }
```

The formbuilder textfield looks like :

```
FormBuilderTextField(
                      attribute: "name",
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
                      validators: [
                        FormBuilderValidators.required(errorText: "Name is required"),
                        FormHorseValidators.isUniqueHorseName(errorText: "Horse already exist."),
                      ],
                    )
```

How is it possible to return valueCandidate when the isUnique value is true or false?

Comment: [flutter_form_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_bloc) support async validators.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into this.